# Is some i2p outproxies for tor only?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, i2p

I believe outproxy to Tor network is safer than outproxy to normal Internet.
So, is more I2P outproxy available for Tor than `false.i2p`?

Answer (score 0):

The default port `4444` has the outproxy "false.i2p" but I check http://127.0.0.1:7657/i2ptunnelmgr then I find out The default port `4445` has the outproxy "outproxy-**tor**.meeh.i2p".
<s>When I  try to use `127.0.0.1:4445` as the proxy for Tor-Browser, I get a lot better experience than use `127.0.0.1:4444`</s>

Answer (score 0):

Well, the ones you've mentioned - are very long-term ones and yes, they are using Tor. I2P has got some good amount of non-public outproxies, and that is how it has to be:

- Same as Tor's exit nodes, outproxies are diversifying the ways/IP zones of the exiting traffic
- Instead of Tor, private outproxy can be easily specified on-flight and used by the I2P client natively, there's no private ExitNode in Tor, sadly - and using proxy/VPN as a hidden service has some additional work to do and has nothing in common with the Tor itself
- I used to spot some in I2P directories - check them